# Tkinter LabelFrame not appearing when using .grid

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a UI using Tkinter that uses LabelFrames and I want to lay them out in a grid. However, they are only appearing when I use the .pack method. I'm not sure if this is because they are a container more than a widget but if someone could help me out that would be great.

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class MainWindow(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tkinter.Tk.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.geometry("788x594")
        self.resizable(False, False)
        self.title("Testing UI")

        Btn = Button(self, text = "Test")
        Btn.grid(column = 0, row = 1)

        testFrame = LabelFrame(self, text = "Test")
        testFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky="EW")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MainWindow(None)
    app.mainloop()
```

And this is the output I get
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rc7SE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The frame *is* appearing. Because there's nothing in the frame, and because you haven't set a size for the frame, it is only 1 pixel wide and 1 pixel tall.

Comment: Wow, that makes a ton of sense! Thanks